# What do these morphemes' abbreviated glosses mean?

Tags: morphology, parts-of-speech, parsing, interlinear-gloss

I am taking a course on linguistics and got introduced to a lot of abbreviations. Other than the obvious `V` for verb, I am having a lot of trouble finding out what the others mean.

The book *Speech and Language Processing* by Jurafsky and Martin uses a lot of these abbreviations too without explaining what they all mean.

Does someone have a link to a list in a website or book or whatever that I can use to know what all these short forms stand for?

I can use google to find out what they mean but am wondering if there is a bigger list out there.

[image]

Comment: Not sure they are using any standard here, they assume the reader understands.  In https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/10.pdf, they explain the Penn Treebank POS tags, which is English-specific.   You can also learn http://universaldependencies.org/u/pos/.  The actual morpho-analysis is usually language-specific and not well standardised.

Comment: Just to make a point, here is spaCy's list: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/morphology.pyx (Ctrl+F for `IDS = `).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the first example

```
blame    blame+V+Inf
```

The word form blame is lemmatised as `blame`, part-of-speech-tagged as verb `V` and and further anylysed as the infinitive `Inf` (which includes all of the present tense except the 3rd person singular `Pres3s`).

The other tags of the example should be no problem: `Pret` stand for the past tense aka *preteritum*, `PastPart` for the past participle and `PresPart` for the present participle aka gerund aka "the -ing form".